# Floyd–Warshall algorithm

Tags: algorithm, floyd-warshall

Is there a simple explanation for why this snippet finds the shortest distance between two vertices

```
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k)
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
      if (d[i][k] + d[k][j] < d[i][j])
        d[i][j] = d[i][k] + d[k][j]
```

and this doesn't

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    for (k = 0; k < n; ++k)
      if (d[i][k] + d[k][j] < d[i][j])
        d[i][j] = d[i][k] + d[k][j]
```

( for k is the innermost one in the second snippet)

Comment: You can resolve uncertainties taking a pencil and observing the adjacency matrix transformation. Look on the classic implementation in http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Floyd-Warshall%27s_Algorithm.c

Answer (score 4):

Because the idea is to try to make paths better by trying to go through node `k` at each step in order to improve every `i - j` path.

The notations do not matter, you can use `i, j, k` as the loop variables instead of `k, i, j` if you want, but you must keep the logic above in mind. In that case, you will want to try to improve the `j - k` paths by going through `i` at each step:

```
for i = 0, n
  for j = 0, n
    for k = 0, n
      if d[j, i] + d[i, k] < d[j, k]
        d[j, k] = d[j, i] + d[i, k]
```

You cannot just reorder the for loops without also changing the condition because you get a different algorithm that way - who knows what it does.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k)
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
      if (d[i][k] + d[k][j] < d[i][j])
        d[i][j] = d[i][k] + d[k][j]
```

The outermost loop `k` is referring to vertices that may be on the path between `Vi` and `Vj`. So when `k=1`, for example, you are considering all paths between vertices `Vi` and `Vj` that include vertex `V1` as in

```
Vi .... V1 .... Vj
```

More importantly, from among those paths you are choosing the best with the relaxation

```
if (d[i][k] + d[k][j] < d[i][j])
        d[i][j] = d[i][k] + d[k][j]
```

Again, each iteration is focussed on two vertices `Vi` and `Vj` and in chooses the best path between them.

In your other instance, the one that fails, you are not choosing the best among paths between two fixed vertices `Vi` and `Vj`, instead you are relaxing all over the place, never waiting long enough to find out which path between two set vertices is the best.

[On Geekviewpoint, a site which I rely on a lot](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/graph/warshall_floyd_all_pairs_shortest_path), they distinctively use `x` and `v` as vertices and `t` for the outermost loop, which makes it easy to remember that `t` is temporary and so not one of the endpoints. (I wish they had actually explained it, since it's not obvious to everyone.)

```
//dynamically find the shortest distance between each pair.
    for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
      for (int v = 0; v < n; v++) {
        for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
          if (dist[v][u] > (long) dist[v][t] + dist[t][u]) {
            dist[v][u] = dist[v][t] + dist[t][u];
            pred[v][u] = pred[t][u];
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a counterexample for the second flawed algorithm.
When i=0, j=1 it will try to find an intermediary, but there isn't any.
Then when an intermediary would be available for i=0, j=1 it is no longer checked again.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you have `K` value in `loop k` that means You are about to add another edge and all possible way to go from `(i->j)` is updated using edges`(1->K-1)`.
Then you insert another edge `K` and you again check if there is any way to go from `(i->j)` in cheaper way using this edge . so you write `d[i][j]=min(d[i][j],d[i][k]+d[k][j])`.

So if you want to write

```
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
     for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
```

Your update should be `d[j][k] = min(d[j][k],d[j][i]+d[i][k])`